# Not able to insert a map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I find a code that allows to get city information. How can I implement this with a simple map https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple?
I would only see this map on my app. the function is the same that is write on the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Reverse Geocoding</title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var geocoder;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 

function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}

function errorFunction(){
    alert("Geocoder failed");
}

  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();



  }

  function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results)
        if (results[1]) {
         //formatted address
         alert(results[0].formatted_address)
        //find country name
             for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
            for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {

            //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                    //this is the object you are looking for
                    city= results[0].address_components[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //city data
        alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name)


        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="initialize()"> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: you'll probably have add a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Without delete or modify the code above, how can implement a Google map?

Comment: There is no map in the posted code.  What map are you asking about?

Comment: @geocodezip No in this code there is no map. I ask to add a map on this code

Comment: Did you try to do that?  What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Yes I try, I insert the code content in the link on description. Is the code that provide Google... but when I start the app I see a blank space...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code in this link 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation.

Then you can copy your function codeLatLng on the new code and invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want show marker use this code:

```
   // options for display map
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

    // color and image point
        var pinColor = "ECECEC";
        var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor,
        pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow";

// display map and marker
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions); var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
                icon: pinImage,
                shadow: pinShadow,
                title: 'Point 1'
              });
```

Comment: for example after :
//city data
        alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name)

and replace 'Point 1' to your current name city

Comment: I've tried to copy the code, but I have the same problem :(

Comment: '06-10 16:43:10.216: E/qdutils(6016): FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO failed
'

Comment: '06-10 16:43:10.216: E/qdmemalloc(6016): heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
'